# How to add an empty space in the Neovim at the bottom of the buffer when using the `set scrolloff` option

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

`scrolloff` is a great feature, but it doesn't work on the last lines of the file. Is there a setting or plugin that allows you to add empty space at the bottom of the file (with '~' in the sign column).
Like view, that gives if you scroll the file with the mouse wheel. Or 'zz' command.

I'm set `scrolloff=10`. And it's uncomfortable to work if there is visually no free space at the bottom. And also I don't like when the autocomplete menu opens up and overlaps the previous text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an autocommand for that :

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "CursorMoved" }, {
  callback = function()

    -- normal buffer (not terminal or prompt)
    if vim.bo.buftype ~= "" then
      return
    end

    local windowLines = vim.api.nvim_win_get_height(0)
    local currLine = vim.fn.line(".")
    local lastLine = vim.fn.line("$")

    -- to handle a file smaller than window
    local bottom = 0
    if windowLines > lastLine then
      bottom = windowLines
    else
      bottom = lastLine
    end

    local marginBottom = currLine + vim.o.scrolloff - bottom
    if marginBottom == 0 then
      vim.api.nvim_input("zb")                    -- align cursor with bottom of file
    elseif marginBottom > 0 then
      vim.api.nvim_input("zb")                    -- align cursor with bottom of file
      vim.api.nvim_input(marginBottom .. "<C-E>") -- scroll down
    end
  end,
})
```

It's a little dirty but it works enough for me.
However, it only works in normal mode. If you want, you can extend the autocommand with the `CursorMovedI` event to work in insert mode (you'll have to make some changes).